# Problema em realizar um Groupby de uma Dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando realizar um *groupy* em um Dataframe que consta casos de covid-19 por estado no brazil. Porém quando passo a função ele me retorna o seguinte erro na figura abaixo. Há casos de estados que se repetem, por isso gostaria de juntar, para ter uma melhor visualização dos dados...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova o argumento `axis=1` do seu código.

Exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'cases': [2, 3, 4, 2, 4], 
...     'state': ['MG', 'MG', 'SC','RS', 'SC']
...     })

>>> df.groupby('state')
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy ...

>>> df.groupby('state').count()
       cases
state       
MG         2
RS         1
SC         2
```

Comment: Bom dia companheiro, deu certo o código acima. Ontem tentei desta mesma forma e infelizmente não estava indo de maneira alguma, até mesmo removendo o axis=1. Porém quando eu realizo essa operação, ao invés dele pegar os dados dos estados que se repetem no dataframe e somar, ele simplesmente me retorna dados inconsistentes, por exemplo, em pernambuco, não ouve nenhuma morte e ele me retorna que 24 pessoas morreram...

Comment: Nesse código que você postou, ele apenas conta as vezes que o nome do estado se repete, e não somar os casos de ocorrência nos estados. Não era para ficar MG = 5, RS = 4, SC = 8 ?

Comment: Não sabia o seu intuito com o código, estava apenas mostrando que meu exemplo forma um objeto `DataFrameGroupBy`, como era esperado. Para somar ocorrências ao invés de contá-las, utilize o método `.sum()` ao invés de `.count()`. Mais informações sobre como trabalhar com objetos `DataFrameGroupBy` [neste guia](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

Comment: Funcionou substituindo *count()* por *sum()*. Desde já, obrigado. Irei dar uma olhada neste guia que você repassou!